# How to glob the buffer-list?

Tags: vimscript, buffers, list

Having a command:

```vim
command! -nargs=+ Foo call s:my_fun(<f-args>)
```

How can I get a glob-match when user say: `Foo *met*.c` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get a list of all buffer names with `getbufinfo()`, here filtering out non listed:

```vim
let buf_list = getbufinfo({'buflisted': 1})
```

Second use `map()` to get the names:

```vim
let buf_list = map(buf_list, 'v:val.name')
```

Third filter out names using `glob2regpat()`, here variable `pattern` being for-example `*.c`:

```vim
let buf_list = filter(buf_list, 'v:val =~# glob2regpat(pattern)')
```

If one want buffer-numbers one can further do:

```vim
let buf_list = map(buf_list, 'bufnr(v:val)')
```

Oneliner:

```vim
filter(map(getbufinfo({'buflisted': 1}), 'v:val.name'), 'v:val =~ glob2regpat("*.c")')
```

---

Dependencies:

```vim
getbufinfo()   " v7.4.2204
map()          " v7.0001
filter()       " v7.0001
glob2regpat()  " v7.4.673
```